# Python - How to remove duplicate cells/rows from CSV based on cell

Tags: python, csv, duplicates

I have a comma separated CSV file of Cities, States, Zip and State Abbreviation. The file has duplicate cites in it with different zip codes. What I need for my output is only 1 city listed and just one zip code, not the same name of a city with all the different zip codes.

Here is what I have in the data (There are 26k lines in the csv file)

```
Phoenix, Arizona, 87654, AZ
Phoenix, Arizona, 87655, AZ
Tuscon, Arizona, 98754, AZ
Tuscon, Arizona, 98755, AZ
Tuscon, Arizona, 98756, AZ
```

What I need is to remove the duplicate city rows and just keep one. So my output needs to look like this.

```
Phoenix, Arizona, 87654, AZ
Tuscon, Arizona, 98756, AZ
```

Here is the code I have at the moment, that is not working.

```
import os, sys, csv

f1 = csv.reader(open('originalcities.csv', 'rb'))
writer = csv.writer(open("output_cities.csv", "wb"))
city = set()
for row in f1:
    if row[1] not in city:
        write.writerow(row)
        city.add( row[1] )
```

I'm not sure if the code is correct for me to get the output I am looking for. When I run this code I get this error.

```
for row in f1:
_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in
text mode?)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The entries are sorted on State? If so, you can compare row[i - 1] with row[i] and keep just one.

Comment: Many cities have multiple zip codes.  What use-case do you have where it makes sense to ignore most of the zip codes in a city?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `row[1]` means you are keeping one entry per STATE.

You should be testing on `(row[0], row[1])` instead (city/state combination, to avoid confusing e.g. Richmond TX with Richmond VA).

```
import csv

IN_FILE  = 'originalcities.csv'
OUT_FILE = 'output_cities.csv'

def main():
    with open(IN_FILE, 'rb') as inf, open(OUT_FILE, 'wb') as outf:
        incsv, outcsv  = csv.reader(inf), csv.writer(outf)

        # read data and de-duplicate by city and state
        citystates = set()
        for row in incsv:
            citystate = tuple(row[0:2])
            if citystate not in citystates:
                outcsv.writeline(row)
                citystates.add(citystate)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

** EDIT: **

Based on @Fernando's suggestion, here is a version that does not need a set, it just compares consecutive lines (this requires that the input data already be in sorted order, or at least that all occurrences of each city/state combination be together).

```
import csv
from itertools import groupby

IN_FILE   = 'originalcities.csv'
OUT_FILE  = 'output_cities.csv'

def main():
    with open(IN_FILE, 'rb') as inf, open(OUT_FILE, 'wb') as outf:
        incsv  = csv.reader(inf)
        outcsv = csv.writer(outf)
        # Read data and de-duplicate by city and state
        # ! assumes data is already in sorted order !
        for citystate,rows in groupby(incsv, key=lambda row: row[0:2]):
            outcsv.writerow(next(rows))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I've been running this code but can't get it to work. I added this line incsv, outcsv  = csv.reader(codecs.iterdecode(inf, 'utf-8')), csv.writer(outf) but still can't get it to run. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: @user1953451: it runs fine for me (Win7x64, Python 2.7.6). Which version of Python are you running?

Comment: I'm using version 3.3.2

Comment: To get the script to work with Python 3.3 you need to change `open(IN_FILE, 'rb')` to `open(IN_FILE, mode='r', newline='')` and similarly, `open(OUT_FILE, 'wb')` should be change to `open(OUT_FILE, mode='w', newline='')`.

Comment: Excellent, thank you @superjump after making those changes the script works perfectly and removes the duplicates as I need them. Thank you Hugh Bothwell and Fernando for helping me find a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

What about using `set` to remove the duplicates?

```
line_sets = []
full_set = []

with open('file.txt') as inp:
    lines = inp.readlines()

    for i in range(0, len(lines)):
        # strip for precaution
        tokens = [w.strip() for w in lines[i].split(',')[0:2]]
        tmp_set = set(tokens)

        if tmp_set not in line_sets:
            full_set.append(lines[i].split(','))
            line_sets.append(tmp_set)

with open('output.txt', 'w') as out:
    for line in full_set:
        out.write(','.join(line))
```

#### output.txt

```
Phoenix,Arizona,87654,AZ
Tuscon,Arizona,98754,AZ
```